# How to split a file into blocks defined by a keyword

Tags: bash

Suppose I have a large text file such as:

```
variableStep chrom=chr1
sometext1
sometext1
sometext1
variableStep chrom=chr2
sometext2
variableStep chrom=chr3
sometext3
sometext3
sometext3
sometext3
```

I would like to split this file into 3 files:
file 1 has the content

```
sometext1
sometext1
sometext2
```

file 2 has the content

```
sometext2
```

and file 3 has the content

```
sometext3
sometext3
sometext3
sometext3
```

Note that none of the "sometext1" "sometext2" "sometext3" will have the word "variableStep".

I can do this in python by simply iterating over the lines and opening a new file handle and write the subsequent lines to it everytime I encounter a "variableStep" in the beginning of the line, however, I am wondering if this can be done on the command line.
Note that the real files are massive (multiple Gbs so reading all the content in one go will not be feasible).

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will create `file1`, `file2`, etc with the desired content:

```
awk '/variableStep/{close(f); f="file" ++c;next} {print>f;}' file
```

#### How it works

- `/variableStep/{close(f); f="file" ++c;next}`

  Every time we reach a line that contains `variableStep`, we close the last file used, assign to `f` the name of the next file to use, and then skip the rest of the commands and jump to the next line.

  `c` is a counter telling us the number for the current file.  It is incremented by `++` every time that we create a new file name.
- `print>f`

  For all other lines, we print them to a file named according to the value of variable `f`.

Since this processes the file line-by-line, it should be suitable even for massive files.

The first output file looks like:

```
$ cat file1
sometext1
sometext1
sometext1
```

Comment: Nice one-liner. Depending on the number of files being created, you might want to add something that closes the last `"file" c` when variableStep is encountered, so that awk doesn't proceed through the file leaving its handles open. Might not be an issue depending on the data, but it would be cleaner.

Comment: @John1024 Thank you for your answer. It's a good solution for my problem.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't ask for an `awk` or `perl` solution, you tagged your question `bash`.  So here goes.

```
while read line; do
  if [[ $line =~ ^variableStep ]]; then
    outputfile="file-${line#chr}.txt"
    continue
  fi
  if [ -n "$outputfile" ]; then
    echo "$line" >> "$outputfile"
  fi
done < inputfile.txt
```

This skips lines at the start of the file until it meets one that contains the pattern used to determine an output file name.  It assumes that for `chrom=chrN` you want to store output in `file-N.txt`.  Salt to taste.

Like John's awk solution, this processes data through a pipe, line by line, so it doesn't matter what size of file you feed it.  You could even use either of these solutions to process stdout of something that's generating this data, though if you did that you'd likely want to adjust the awk solution to close its output files after writing.

If maintaining consistent file numbers isn't important, you can simplify things a bit. For example:

```
n=0
while read line; do
  case "$line" in
    variableStep*) ((n++)); continue ;;
  esac
  echo "$line" >> file-${n}.txt
done < inputfile.txt
```

In this example, we're evaluating the content of the line using a `case` statement pattern match instead of a regular expression in an `if` statement.  Generally, pattern matching is faster than regular expression matching.  If it matters to you, you should conduct a test on your actual data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your solution is quite good as well.